# Setting Border Style for a Table in Apache POI XSLF

Tags: apache-poi, xslf

Currently in Apache POI XSLF only the following styles are available in StrokeStyle Class for setting the border style for a XSLFTableCell:

1.LineDash:
SOLID,
DOT,
DASH,
DASH_DOT,
LG_DASH,
LG_DASH_DOT,
SYS_DASH,
SYS_DOT,
SYS_DASH_DOT,
SYS_DASH_DOT_DOT;

2.LineCompound:
SINGLE,
DOUBLE,
THICK_THIN,
THIN_THICK,
TRIPLE;

How do i set the following styles- groove,ridge, inset and outset?
if these are not explicitly available, how do i set them using the above styles?

Would appreciate if anyone knows about this and can help out.

Comment: xslf files are zip files with xml files inside them. Unzip a sample file with the right styles in it and find out what the XML looks like. You can then try to write code that produces similar XML. POI can do the basics and you can then edit the POI generated file to reset the styles.

Comment: What are styles groove, ridge, inset and outset in a PowerPoint Table? How would you set this styles using PowerPoint? Do yu mean cell 3D settings like cell bevel?

Comment: I'm converting a html to a ppt using apache POI XSLF. In the html, different table border styles are provided- 4 of them being groove, ridge, inset and outset. I have been able to produce all other styles except these through xslf

Comment: @PJFanning I have tried checking these in powerpoint, i don't see these border styles in powerpoint. Hence apache poi doesn't have them i guess